# How to deploy java spring restful service on AWS based on tomcat server with mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-rest

I have restful spring web service running on tomcat server and have mysql database on backend. I deployed war file of my service using aws elastic beanstalk free account yet but I am unable to setup mysql database. Can anyone guide me on this matter ? Secondly, our application has android side code which will call my REST API so is there any other way to do this instead of setting up amazon web services for testing purposes ?

Comment: there is a AWS Toolkit for Eclipse, within this toolkit you should deploy within just one click on eclipse, As  this [AWS tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/aws-web-app-deployment-java/) sayed that The AWS Toolkit for Eclipse provides the easiest and most straightforward way to deploy custom Java applications to AWS

Comment: The AWS service for running databases is RDS. You will want to start an RDS server to host your database and have your app servers that are running in elastic beanstalk connect to your RDS server.

Comment: @FadySaad thanks for help but as I am using intellij Idea there is one AWS manager for it but it does not work because of its preference settings issues according to the community using it. But I am going to try it.

Comment: @Rob if we have free account yet on Amazon, can we still configure RDS ?

Comment: @TalhaZahid Yes, there is free-tier for RDS: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/

Comment: @Rob thanks for your help. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going the right way; Android should call REST APIs. These APIs can be implemented in following ways:

1. As you suggested; use spring on tomcat to expose such apis.
2. Use API Gateway exposed by AWS. This api gateway can even call lambda expressions in backend which can be written in Java/Python etc.

I will suggest you to go ahead with 1 as u are already aware of spring/tomcat etc. and MOST companies use this only.

For MySQL database you have following options:

1. Install MySQL on your local EC2 server ( where you have tomcat running ); or on another EC2 server.
2. You can use MySQL as a service which is RDS. It is expensive but easy to configure.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but I didnt get your point to setup MySQL on local EC2. I have my application deployed on elastic beanstalk and want to setup MySQL now. So should I use amazon EC2 servers for MySQL and my application ?

Comment: Ideal solution in Elastic BeanStalk is that you have database on different EC2 server. You can search for ami LAMP or MySQL and start that EC2.. MySQL would already be installed on that server. Or you can manually install MySQL on Ubuntu by apt-get command

Comment: please note that usually, the MySQL server will not allow connections from out, meaning the only localhost is allowed and must to enable the IP address of that host which going to connect to MySQL

P.S. Enabling wildcard % for host is not a good practice at all